# px.line with plotly: How can I set multiple axes based on the color parameter?

Tags: plotly, dashboard, linechart

I want to construct a line chart in my dashboard for two districts in Somalia (Jowhar and Balcad) each containing two measures: the RFE and the CDI. My goal is that through the use of a dropdown menu I can select which district I want and immediately the line chart will deploy mi two measures for this place.

The problem that I encountered is that these two measures (comprised within the column "Indicator") have completely different scales, one is ranging between 0 and 1, and the other between 200 and 400. As a result, my graph shows only the latter. How could I set two y axes?

Below my attemp without any success:

```
@app.callback(
Output('line-chart','figure'),
Input('my-date-picker-start','date'),
Input('my-date-picker-end','date'),
Input('my_dropdown','value'),)

def update_pie(start_date, end_date, district):
line_1 = cdi_rfe.copy()
line_1 = line_1[(line_1['year']>=start_date) & (line_1['year']<=end_date)]

fig = px.line(line_1, x='year', y=district, color='Indicator', template='plotly_dark',
                    color_discrete_sequence=["#FE9235", "#E7E6E6"],
                    labels={'year':'Year', 'Balcad':'mm', 'Jowhar':'mm'})
fig2 = px.line(drought, x='year', y=district, color='measure', template='plotly_dark',
                   color_discrete_sequence=C["#FE9235", "#E7E6E6"])
fig2.update_traces(yaxis ="y2")
fig.add_traces(fig2.data).update_layout(yaxis2={"overlaying":"y", "side":"right"})
fig.update_layout(margin=dict(l=20, r=20, t=30, b=20))  
fig.update_xaxes(tickangle=-45)
fig.update_layout(
title=dict(
    text="Total annual rainfall (mm) & Combined Drought Index",
    font=dict(size=18),
    y=0.98,
    x=0.5, ))    

return fig
```